String search values in a class, with List and Maps
We are trying to search a class and all its fields for a specific search string. Does Java contain a native library to search values in a class? Otherwise, I wrote a basic method below.
public class Account {
    private String accountId;
    private Set<String> contactIds = new HashSet<>();
    private Map<String, String> phones = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<String, String> emails = new HashMap<>();
    private Set<String> titles = new HashSet<>();
}

Attempt:
private boolean hasSearchString(Account account, String seachString) {
    for (String item: account.getContactNames()) {
         if (item.contains(searchString))
            return true;
    }
    for (String item: account.getPhones().keySet()) {
        if (item.contains(searchString))
           return true;
    }
    for (String title: account.getEmails().keySet()) {
        if (item.contains(searchString))
           return true;
    }
    ....
}


No, there's no built-in code to do that. But what you have looks fine.

I just created a basic example,  im working with legacy code,  just more interested in search functionality cc @OldDogProgrammer

ok thanks @shmosel maybe is there a Apache library, or 3rd party? otherwise will stick with that

Java Reflection?.

If your class is really complicated, with lots of fields, and Strings at many levels into the tree, then you could consider solving this using reflection.  This will be REALLY HARD - there are lots of curly things to consider, like polymorphism, inner classes, circular references and so on.  I'm not aware of any library that will do this for you painlessly.  If your class is similar to the example you've posted here, it's DEFINITELY not worth it.

tl;dr
No. There is no way for Java to automatically search the content of your objects in a way that meets the business rules of your app’s domain.
Making sense of your domain’s data is your job, not Java’s.
Tip: Learn about the Repository pattern commonly used to encapsulate access to a data store such as a database.
Terms
Correct some terms…

search a class and all its fields

The class is the template for making objects at runtime. Like a cookie-cutter stamps out cookies.
So you want to search the content in the fields of the objects, not the class.

Java Library contain a native library to search values

The term native means non-Java code, code written in C or Rust or Swift or such that is compiled ahead-of-time to machine-language.
In contrast, Java is compiled to bytecode. Later, at runtime, that bytecode is interpreted or compiled to machine language.
OOP design
Your example data-structure is not object-oriented.
Apparently you mean for an Account to represent a group of contacts, where a contact is a person with an id, a name, a phone number, an email address, and a title.
So create a custom class to represent each of your entities: account, and contact.
If the main purpose of your custom class is to transparently communicate shallowly-immutable data, then define the class as a record.
package work.basil.example.searching;

import java.util.UUID;

public record Contact( UUID id , String name , String title , String email , String phone ) { }

package work.basil.example.searching;

import java.util.Collection;

public record Account( String name , Collection < Contact > contacts ) { }

Repository
To manage access to your data store, create a class dedicated to that purpose. Commonly named Repository.  In our implementation of Repository here, we create some fake data for this demo.
package work.basil.example.searching;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class Repository
{
    // Fields.
    private final Collection < Account > accounts;

    // Constructors
    public Repository ( )
    {
        this.accounts = this.fetchAccounts ( );
    }

    public Account fetchAccountByName ( final String aName )
    {
        for ( Account account : this.accounts )
        {
            if ( account.name ( ).equalsIgnoreCase ( aName ) ) { return account; }
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Helpers
    private List < Account > fetchAccounts ( )
    {
        return
                List.of (
                        new Account (
                                "West" ,
                                List.of (
                                        new Contact ( UUID.fromString ( "0fc8ebc7-e8ef-4a5f-8788-b8d2a18b470a" ) , "Alice" , "Boss" , "alice@aol.com" , "555-1234" ) ,
                                        new Contact ( UUID.fromString ( "14f9e482-8e59-4e75-8955-5b3bc13e52ff" ) , "Bob" , "Secretary" , "bob@aol.com" , "555-4321" ) ,
                                        new Contact ( UUID.fromString ( "db0a0a51-cd88-4d2e-8cf7-45535f1cf09b" ) , "Carol" , "Engineer" , "carol@aol.com" , "555-2345" )
                                )
                        ) ,
                        new Account (
                                "East" ,
                                List.of (
                                        new Contact ( UUID.fromString ( "013da36d-cc0f-4c07-b9ab-077cbf152025" ) , "Davis" , "Boss" , "davis@acme.com" , "555-7890" ) ,
                                        new Contact ( UUID.fromString ( "9f4282aa-1ea5-4c3f-888c-abe68135c489" ) , "Edna" , "Secretary" , "edna@acme.com" , "555-0987" ) ,
                                        new Contact ( UUID.fromString ( "184ca072-b945-48bb-ba9f-4423df857837" ) , "Frank" , "Engineer" , "frank@acme.com" , "555-8907" )
                                )
                        )
                );
    }
}

Searching
Notice how we have a method fetchAccountByName to return a particular account by its name, "West" or "East" given our fake data.
Example usage:
Repository repository = new Repository ( );
Account eastAccount = repository.fetchAccountByName ( "East" );
System.out.println ( "eastAccount.toString() = " + eastAccount );


eastAccount.toString() = Account[name=East, contacts=[Contact[id=013da36d-cc0f-4c07-b9ab-077cbf152025, name=Davis, title=Boss, email=davis@acme.com, phone=555-7890], Contact[id=9f4282aa-1ea5-4c3f-888c-abe68135c489, name=Edna, title=Secretary, email=edna@acme.com, phone=555-0987], Contact[id=184ca072-b945-48bb-ba9f-4423df857837, name=Frank, title=Engineer, email=frank@acme.com, phone=555-8907]]]

Apparently you want to search for accounts where one or more contacts have a particular name. So let's add another method to our Repository class.
public Collection < Contact > fetchContactByPersonName ( final String aContactName )
{
    ArrayList < Contact > foundContacts = new ArrayList <> ( );
    for ( Account account : this.accounts )
    {
        for ( Contact contact : account.contacts ( ) )
        {
            if ( contact.name ( ).equalsIgnoreCase ( aContactName ) )
            {
                foundContacts.add ( contact );
            }
        }
    }
    return List.copyOf ( foundContacts );  // Generally best to return an unmodifiable list.
}

Search for contacts named Frank.
Collection < Contact > contactsNamedFrank = repository.fetchContactByPersonName ( "Frank" );
System.out.println ( "contactsNamedFrank.toString() = " + contactsNamedFrank );


contactsNamedFrank.toString() = [Contact[id=184ca072-b945-48bb-ba9f-4423df857837, name=Frank, title=Engineer, email=frank@acme.com, phone=555-8907]]

Search for a name that does not exist. We expect an empty collection.
Collection < Contact > contactsNamedZappa = repository.fetchContactByPersonName ( "Zappa" );
System.out.println ( "contactsNamedZappa.toString() = " + contactsNamedZappa );


contactsNamedZappa.toString() = []

Reflection
Java does support reflective programming. You can, at runtime, query a class for its structure, to see its fields.
But this is complicated, and tricky to get right. Later changes to your code may ruin your reflection code. Generally, using reflection is a last-resort solution.
